# FitDist ERROR: 'data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1'

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I am trying to fit a distribution using the following code:

```
fit.gamma <- fitdist(x, distr = "gamma", method = "mle")
```

I get the following error:

Error in fitdist(x, distr = "gamma", method = "mle") : 
data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1

X is a numeric variable. It looks like this when plotted.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUdEW.png)

Why do I get this error. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `class(x)`, better yet `str(x)`. What do they return? Can you post the output of `dput(x)` or if it's big of `dput(head(x, 20))` in the question, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
> class(x)
[1] "numeric"
> str(x)
 atomic [1:18839] 7 175 386 375 397 333 378 394 330 346 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  int [1:17] 1 209 267 286 288 297 299 300 304 305 ...
> dput(head(x, 20))
c(7, 175, 386, 375, 397, 333, 378, 394, 330, 346, 306, 344, 308, 
278, 291, 284, 252, 294, 277, 241)
```

Thanks

Comment: I found the solution myself. I loaded the dataset from .dta format using read.dta.  There must a bug in this package, because I tried saving it as csv and loading it using read_csv and the error message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that you used `na.omit`, which doesn't return a vector like `fitdist` is expecting.

Instead of this

```
x <- na.omit(x.init)
fit.gamma <- fitdist(x, distr = "gamma", method = "mle")
```

try converting the output of `na.omit` to a vector

```
x <- c(na.omit(x.init))
fit.gamma <- fitdist(x, distr = "gamma", method = "mle")
```